# euler method in numerical differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

would someone please explain the solution for this question ? i have no idea how to prove it.

> problem:
> The linear system $Y'=AY$ with $Y(0)= Y_0$, where $A$ is a symmetric matrix, is solved using Euler's method.

Letting $\mathrm{e}_{n}=\mathbf{y}_{n}-\mathbf{Y}(n h)$ with $n=0,1,...$ prove that:

$$\left\|\mathbf{e}_{n}\right\|_{2} \leq\left\|\mathbf{Y}_{0}\right\|_{2} \max _{\lambda \in \sigma(A)}\left|(1+h \lambda)^{n}-e^{n h \lambda}\right|$$

Comment: Can you solve the task when $A$ is a diagonal matrix? What do you know about the diagonalization of symmetric matrices?

Comment: i know about diagonalizing a matrix using its eigen values but no idea how to apply it in this problem .

Comment: Can you prove the claim for the scalar case?

Comment: sadly , no i can't

Comment: In the scalar case you can just solve the recursion as well as the equation and subtract...

Comment: But you know that for $y'=λy$ you get $y_n=(1+λh)^ny_0$ and $y(t_n)=e^{nh}$?

Comment: If $A$ is hermitian then it has real eigenvalues. Also we can make $A = T^{-1}\Lambda T$ with $\Lambda$ the diagonal eigenvalues matrix. So we have $\dot Y = T^{-1}\Lambda T Y$ or Euler discretizing  $y_{k+1} = y_k +h\Lambda y_k$. This recurrence has as solution $y_k = \left(I+h\Lambda\right)^k y_0$ and converges if $\max_i|1+h\lambda _i| \lt 1$. etc.